# On the $S^n$, whether smooth Riemannian metric $g$ will become constant (sectional) curvature metric under Ricci flow?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Recently, I read the Hamilton's *An isoperimetric estimate for the Ricci flow on the two sphere*. He state that Chow proved that Under the Ricci flow on 2-sphere, any metric approaches constant curvature.

Then, I Google that whether the metric on $S^n  (n\ge 3)$ will approach constant setional curvature metric. But there is not useful result.

In  fact, I feel there should be some metric will not become constant curvature metric on $S^n$ under Ricci flow. But I don't know how to  construct an example. Therefore, asking help here for how to construct it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When $n=3$, the [seminal work](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-17/issue-2/Three-manifolds-with-positive-Ricci-curvature/10.4310/jdg/1214436922.full) of Hamilton shows that any closed 3-manifold with positive Ricci curvature converges to the constant curvature metric under the (normalized) Ricci flow. When $n=4$, Hamilton also has a [similar result](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-24/issue-2/Four-manifolds-with-positive-curvature-operator/10.4310/jdg/1214440433.full), assuming that the closed manifold has positive curvature tensor. More recently Bohm and Wilking show in this [paper](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v167-n3-p10.pdf) the same conclusion holds if the manifold has 2-positive curvature operator in any $n\ge 3$. Building on the idea of Bohm and Wilking, Brendle and Schoen use Ricci flow to prove the [differentiable sphere theorem](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2009-22-01/S0894-0347-08-00613-9/S0894-0347-08-00613-9.pdf).

In general, as the other answer suggests, singularities develop under Ricci flow even when $n=3$. For example, Angenent and Knopf [construct](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/pages/journals/items/mrl/content/vols/0011/0004/a008/) explicit examples of type I singularity for Ricci flow in the sphere in any dimension. More complicated singularities (the so called degenerate neckpinches) are later [constructed](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crelle-2013-0105/pdf) by Angenent, Isenberg and Knopf.

Comment: Thanks, Angenent and Knopf 's paper is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is true, even if $n=3$. Perelman used the Ricci flow to prove the Poincare conjecture in 2002. The main difficulty was to deal with the singularities that appear when applying the Ricci flow on a 3-dimensional manifold. So I suggest you read a bit on the work of Perelman. There are many introductory articles on the subject.